# How to send keys to input field that is created by javascript using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send keys using Selenium to an input field which is created by javaScript. I am using selenium web driver with chrome driver and in python.

I have tried following methods but it gives the same error that "element not interactable" when even I can access the input element.

Tried following function:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']")[0]
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']")
find_element_by_class()
find_element_by_id()
find_element_by_css_selector()
```

my exact code is:

```
print("Filling Engine Number")
input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='o_form_input ui-autocomplete-input']")
# input.clear()
time.sleep(2)
input.send_keys("Engine Numbers")
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Oasis3/PycharmProjects/dataScrapping/ERP.py", line 309, in <module>
    input.send_keys(product_title)
  File "C:\Users\Oasis3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Oasis3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Oasis3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Oasis3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Is there any solution to that problem?
screen shots are attached.

[image]
..
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: can you share us what have you tried..^.^

Comment: edited the question, and last screenshot is given of my code

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code. Use [edit] and paste your formatted code in then highlight it and press Ctrl + K. Include the url if possible otherwise include the html using the snippet tool.

Comment: can you try to access the parent of input that is div have you if not then please and let us know

Comment: yes I can access parent div, after using print(input.get_attribute('innerHTML')), im getting <input class="o_form_input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" id="o_field_input_19" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="o_dropdown_button" draggable="false"></span>

Comment: make a click on input and then try to send keys

Comment: Could you post the error stack and the HTML for the elements with some of the parent nodes?

Comment: @SAhmed, even I am able to access the input element but when It send keys it gives following error:

in <module> input.send_keys('hello world')
in send_keys  'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params)
in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
Exception: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Please add the error and HTML in the post.

Comment: @SAhmed, edited the whole question.

Comment: Since it has been flagged as duplicate, have you tried the solution in that question?

Comment: @SAhmed, yes, I have already tried that solution, but of no use of me... I am getting the error only when I try to send keys to the input when Input is accessible and I can print its class too.